# Programa se cierra al poner el plano x en logaritmico al momento de graficar

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Hola estoy diseñando un programa que me diseña una bocina a partir de ciertos parametros. Una vez ingresados estos datos el programa arroja 3 grafica una con su diseño y otras 2 que grafiquen la admiancia e impedancia de radiación. El problema es que necesito las 2 ultimas graficas en el plano x como logaritmica. Al correr el programa y darle graficar se cierra.

Este es el codigo:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QMessageBox, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIntValidator, QDoubleValidator
from PyQt5.QtCore import QLocale
import math
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import NavigationToolbar2QT
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np


#Clase Heredada de QMainWindow (Constructor de ventana)
class Ventana(QMainWindow):
      #Metodo constructor de la clase
      def __init__(self):
            #Iniciar el objeto QMainWindow
            QMainWindow.__init__(self)
            #Cargar la Configuracion del archivo ui en el objeto
            uic.loadUi("Bocinas.ui",self)
            self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.Guardar)
            #Convierte los valores en float e int
            self._int_validator = QIntValidator()
            self._float_validator = QDoubleValidator()
            self.lineEdit.setValidator(self._float_validator)
            self.lineEdit_2.setValidator(self._int_validator)
            self.lineEdit_3.setValidator(self._float_validator)
            self.lineEdit_4.setValidator(self._float_validator)
            self.lineEdit_5.setValidator(self._float_validator)
            #Pone los lineEdit en 0 predeterminado
            self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText("0")
            self.lineEdit_2.setPlaceholderText("0")
            self.lineEdit_3.setPlaceholderText("0")
            self.lineEdit_4.setPlaceholderText("0")
            self.lineEdit_5.setPlaceholderText("0")
            self._locale = QLocale()
            #Declaracion de Widget para grafica
            self.figure = Figure()
            self.canvas = FigureCanvasQTAgg(self.figure)
            self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar2QT(self.canvas, self.widget)
            self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
            self.plot_layout = QVBoxLayout()
            self.plot_layout.addWidget(self.toolbar)
            self.plot_layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
            self.widget.setLayout(self.plot_layout)

            self.figure2 = Figure()
            self.canvas2 = FigureCanvasQTAgg(self.figure2)
            self.toolbar2 = NavigationToolbar2QT(self.canvas2, self.widget_2)
            self.axes2 = self.figure2.add_subplot(111)
            self.plot_layout2 = QVBoxLayout()
            self.plot_layout2.addWidget(self.toolbar2)
            self.plot_layout2.addWidget(self.canvas2)
            self.widget_2.setLayout(self.plot_layout2)

            self.figure3 = Figure()
            self.canvas3 = FigureCanvasQTAgg(self.figure3)
            self.toolbar3 = NavigationToolbar2QT(self.canvas3, self.widget_3)
            self.axes3 = self.figure3.add_subplot(111)
            self.plot_layout3 = QVBoxLayout()
            self.plot_layout3.addWidget(self.toolbar3)
            self.plot_layout3.addWidget(self.canvas3)
            self.widget_3.setLayout(self.plot_layout3)



      def closeEvent(self,event):
            resultado = QMessageBox.question(self,"Salir..","¿Seguro quiere salir?",QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No)
            if resultado == QMessageBox.Yes:
                  event.accept()
            else:
                  event.ignore()

      def Guardar(self):
            st, _ = self._locale.toDouble(self.lineEdit.text())
            l, _ = self._locale.toInt(self.lineEdit_2.text())
            xo, _ = self._locale.toDouble(self.lineEdit_3.text())
            m, _ = self._locale.toDouble(self.lineEdit_4.text())
            M, _ = self._locale.toDouble(self.lineEdit_5.text())
            sx=[]
            x=[]
            if self.radioButton.isChecked():
                  ls=l+1
                  for i in range(ls):
                        s=st*((i/xo)**2)
                        sx.append(s)
                        x.append(i)
            elif self.radioButton_2.isChecked():
                  ls=l+1
                  for i in range(ls):
                        d=((m*i)/2)
                        d1=math.cosh(d)
                        s=st*(d1**2)
                        sx.append(s)
                        x.append(i)
            elif self.radioButton_3.isChecked():
                  ls=l+1
                  for i in range(ls):
                        s=st*((math.cosh((m*i)/2))+(M*math.sinh(m*i)/2)**2)
                        sx.append(s)
                        x.append(i)
            elif self.radioButton_4.isChecked():
                  ls=l+1
                  for i in range(ls):
                        s=st*math.exp(m*i)
                        sx.append(s)
                        x.append(i)
            else:
                  QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Advertencia', "Seleccione algun tipo de Bocina",QMessageBox.Retry)

            self.axes.clear()
            self.axes.plot(x, sx,'b--')
            self.axes.set_title("Bocina")
            self.axes.plot(x, sx,'b--')
            self.axes.grid(True)
            self.canvas.draw()

            rho = 1.2
            c = 340
            fs = np.array((31.2, 63, 125, 250, 500, 1000, 2000, 4000, 8000, 16000, 21000))
            ks = (2 * np.pi * fs) / c
            zmr = (rho * c * ((1j * ks * st) / (1 + (1j * ks * st))))
            real = np.real(zmr)
            imaginaria = np.imag(zmr)


            self.axes2.clear()
            self.axes2.plot(fs, real,'r--')
            self.axes2.set_title("Impedancia de Radicion")
            self.axes2.grid(True)
            self.axes2.plot(fs, real,'r--')
            self.axes2.xscale('log')
            self.canvas2.draw()

            self.axes3.clear()
            self.axes3.plot(fs, imaginaria,'g--')
            self.axes3.set_title("Admitancia de Radiacion")
            self.axes3.grid(True)
            self.axes3.plot(fs, imaginaria,'g--')
            self.axes3.xscale('log')
            self.canvas3.draw()

#Instancia para iniciar una app
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
#Crear un objeto de la clase
_ventana = Ventana()
#Mostrar ventana
_ventana.show()
#Ejecutar app
app.exec_()
```

El problema es que necesito las 2 ultimas graficas en el plano x como logaritmica. Al correr el programa y darle graficar se cierra.

Gracias por la atencion

Comment: Vale ya lo probé con el cambio de from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2Q, sin embargo sigue cerrandose el programa solo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dos cosa:

- No uses el backend de Matplotlib para Qt4 en una aplicación para PyQt5. En vez de :

  ```
  from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg
  from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import NavigationToolbar2QT
  ```

  haz :

  ```
  from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg, NavigationToolbar2QT
  ```
- `matplotlib.axes.Axes` no tiene ningún método llamado `xscale`. Dicho método pertenece a 
  `matplotlib.pyplot`. En su lugar debes usar `matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xscale`:

  ```
  self.axes2.clear()
  self.axes2.set_title("Impedancia de Radicion")
  self.axes2.grid(True)
  self.axes2.plot(fs, real,'r--')
  self.axes2.set_xscale('log')
  self.canvas2.draw()

  self.axes3.clear()
  self.axes3.set_title("Admitancia de Radiacion")
  self.axes3.grid(True)
  self.axes3.plot(fs, imaginaria,'g--')
  self.axes3.set_xscale('log')
  self.canvas3.draw()
  ```

  o usa [matplotlib.axes.Axes.semilogyx](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.semilogx.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.semilogx) directamente:

  ```
  self.axes2.clear()
  self.axes2.set_title("Impedancia de Radicion")
  self.axes2.grid(True)
  self.axes2.semilogx(fs, real,'r--')
  self.canvas2.draw()

  self.axes3.clear()
  self.axes3.set_title("Admitancia de Radiacion")
  self.axes3.grid(True)
  self.axes3.semilogx(fs, imaginaria,'g--')
  self.canvas3.draw()
  ```